# Custom Cell Reorder Behavior in CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am able to reorder my collectionView like so:

[image]

However, instead of all cells shifting horizontally, I would just like to swap with the following behavior (i.e. with less shuffling of cells):

[image]

I have been playing with the following delegate method:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, targetIndexPathForMoveFromItemAt originalIndexPath: IndexPath, toProposedIndexPath proposedIndexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath
```

however, I am unsure how I can achieve custom reordering behavior.

Comment: Did you have any luck finding any answer? I am stuck on this as well.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I managed to achieve this by creating a subclass of `UICollectionView` and adding custom handling to interactive movement. While looking at possible hints on how to solve your issue, I've found this tutorial : http://nshint.io/blog/2015/07/16/uicollectionviews-now-have-easy-reordering/.
The most important part there was that interactive reordering can be done not only on `UICollectionViewController`. The relevant code looks like this :

```
var longPressGesture : UILongPressGestureRecognizer!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // rest of setup        

    longPressGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.handleLongGesture(_:)))
    self.collectionView?.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)

}

func handleLongGesture(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

    switch(gesture.state) {

    case UIGestureRecognizerState.Began:
        guard let selectedIndexPath = self.collectionView?.indexPathForItemAtPoint(gesture.locationInView(self.collectionView)) else {
            break
        }
        collectionView?.beginInteractiveMovementForItemAtIndexPath(selectedIndexPath)
    case UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed:
        collectionView?.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(gesture.locationInView(gesture.view!))
    case UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended:
        collectionView?.endInteractiveMovement()
    default:
        collectionView?.cancelInteractiveMovement()
    }
}
```

This needs to be inside your view controller in which your collection view is placed. I don't know if this will work with `UICollectionViewController`, some additional tinkering may be needed. What led me to subclassing `UICollectionView` was realisation that all other related classes/delegate methods are informed only about the first and last index paths (i.e. the source and destination), and there is no information about all the other cells that got rearranged, so It needed to be stopped at the core.

**SwappingCollectionView.swift** :

```
import UIKit

extension UIView {
    func snapshot() -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size)
        self.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}

extension CGPoint {
    func distanceToPoint(p:CGPoint) -> CGFloat {
        return sqrt(pow((p.x - x), 2) + pow((p.y - y), 2))
    }
}

struct SwapDescription : Hashable {
    var firstItem : Int
    var secondItem : Int

    var hashValue: Int {
        get {
            return (firstItem * 10) + secondItem
        }
    }
}

func ==(lhs: SwapDescription, rhs: SwapDescription) -> Bool {
    return lhs.firstItem == rhs.firstItem && lhs.secondItem == rhs.secondItem
}

class SwappingCollectionView: UICollectionView {

    var interactiveIndexPath : NSIndexPath?
    var interactiveView : UIView?
    var interactiveCell : UICollectionViewCell?
    var swapSet : Set<SwapDescription> = Set()
    var previousPoint : CGPoint?

    static let distanceDelta:CGFloat = 2 // adjust as needed

    override func beginInteractiveMovementForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {

        self.interactiveIndexPath = indexPath

        self.interactiveCell = self.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)

        self.interactiveView = UIImageView(image: self.interactiveCell?.snapshot())
        self.interactiveView?.frame = self.interactiveCell!.frame

        self.addSubview(self.interactiveView!)
        self.bringSubviewToFront(self.interactiveView!)

        self.interactiveCell?.hidden = true

        return true
    }

    override func updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(targetPosition: CGPoint) {

        if (self.shouldSwap(targetPosition)) {

            if let hoverIndexPath = self.indexPathForItemAtPoint(targetPosition), let interactiveIndexPath = self.interactiveIndexPath {

                let swapDescription = SwapDescription(firstItem: interactiveIndexPath.item, secondItem: hoverIndexPath.item)

                if (!self.swapSet.contains(swapDescription)) {

                    self.swapSet.insert(swapDescription)

                    self.performBatchUpdates({
                        self.moveItemAtIndexPath(interactiveIndexPath, toIndexPath: hoverIndexPath)
                        self.moveItemAtIndexPath(hoverIndexPath, toIndexPath: interactiveIndexPath)
                        }, completion: {(finished) in
                            self.swapSet.remove(swapDescription)                                
                            self.dataSource?.collectionView(self, moveItemAtIndexPath: interactiveIndexPath, toIndexPath: hoverIndexPath)
                            self.interactiveIndexPath = hoverIndexPath

                    })
                }
            }
        }

        self.interactiveView?.center = targetPosition
        self.previousPoint = targetPosition
    }

    override func endInteractiveMovement() {
        self.cleanup()
    }

    override func cancelInteractiveMovement() {
        self.cleanup()
    }

    func cleanup() {
        self.interactiveCell?.hidden = false
        self.interactiveView?.removeFromSuperview()
        self.interactiveView = nil
        self.interactiveCell = nil
        self.interactiveIndexPath = nil
        self.previousPoint = nil
        self.swapSet.removeAll()
    }

    func shouldSwap(newPoint: CGPoint) -> Bool {
        if let previousPoint = self.previousPoint {
            let distance = previousPoint.distanceToPoint(newPoint)
            return distance < SwappingCollectionView.distanceDelta
        }

        return false
    }
}
```

I do realize that there is a lot going on there, but I hope everything will be clear in a minute.

1. Extension on `UIView` with helper method to get a snapshot of a cell.
2. Extension on `CGPoint` with helper method to calculate distance between two points.
3. `SwapDescription` helper structure - it is needed to prevent multiple swaps of the same pair of items, which resulted in glitchy animations. Its `hashValue` method could be improved, but was good enough for the sake of this proof of concept.
4. `beginInteractiveMovementForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool` - the method called when the movement begins. Everything gets setup here. We get a snapshot of our cell and add it as a subview - this snapshot will be what the user actually drags on screen. The cell itself gets hidden. If you return `false` from this method, the interactive movement will not begin.
5. `updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(targetPosition: CGPoint)` - method called after each user movement, which is a lot. We check if the distance from previous point is small enough to swap items - this prevents issue when the user would drag fast across screen and multiple items would get swapped with non-obvious results. If the swap can happen, we check if it is already happening, and if not we swap two items.
6. `endInteractiveMovement()`, `cancelInteractiveMovement()`, `cleanup()` - after the movement ends, we need to restore our helpers to their default state.
7. `shouldSwap(newPoint: CGPoint) -> Bool` - helper method to check if the movement was small enough so we can swap cells.

This is the result it gives :

[image: result]

Let me know if this is what you needed and/or if you need me to clarify something.

Here is a [demo project](https://github.com/Losiowaty/SwappingCollectionView).

Comment: This is a fantastic solution and explanation. The one issue I am now facing though is that my 'collectionView(moveItemAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath)" method is no longer getting called. This is where I was handling my data after the cell changes. Thank you.

Comment: Yikes, I knew I forgot about something! I've edited my answer - the important thing happened in completion block of `performBatchUpdates` - a call to the mentioned method on datasource.

Comment: Awesome, now it gets called. Also (in regards to handling the data), instead of removing and reinserting the object at the sourceIndexPath.row of my array, I now just swap the item at the source with the destination. Thanks!

Comment: One question I have is if you notice that when you drag to a new location quickly, the animation looks a bit fabricated. For example, if you quickly drag to a spot in the top left, it will show the animation of the item coming all the way from its original location, instead of just placing it there from where you currently have it dragged. Otherwise this is perfect.

Comment: Well, i haven't done such thorough testing ;) one thing you may try to make the animation look more natural (especially when the distance is long) is to replace the autamatic animation done by `performBatchUpdates` with `UIView.animateWithDuration`. This will let you set `CurveEaseInOut` option for example - the item will gradually speed up and then slow down. This feels nore natural then linear movement. This requires some more code to be written though.

Comment: @Losiowaty, awesome answer. Can you provide a git link to your project with your works? That will be super helpful.

Comment: Well, the code posted above is actually about everything you need. Still, here it is wrapped in a project : https://github.com/Losiowaty/SwappingCollectionView

Comment: @Losiowaty Thanks for the tip; I have tried fiddling with that but still no luck but I will keep trying. Also posted the question here for now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39217683/duplicated-cell-animation-during-batch-update

Comment: Is it available in Objective C

Comment: @AnilGupta, yes. As far as the SDK goes everything is available in both Objective-C and Swift. Transferring it to Obj-C shouldn't be that hard either.

Comment: @AnilGupta did you get Objective C version

Comment: @Losiowaty i convert it in objective c , but i have a problem , i need paging on it, i mean i have 3 page in collection i need that page will change if my scroll postition is   at last index

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5 solution of @Losiowaty solution:

```
var longPressGesture : UILongPressGestureRecognizer!

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // rest of setup
    longPressGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleLongGesture))
    self.collectionView?.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)
}

@objc func handleLongGesture(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer)
{
    switch(gesture.state)
    {
    case UIGestureRecognizerState.began:
        guard let selectedIndexPath = self.collectionView?.indexPathForItem(at: gesture.location(in: self.collectionView)) else {
            break
        }
        collectionView?.beginInteractiveMovementForItem(at: selectedIndexPath)
    case UIGestureRecognizerState.changed:
        collectionView?.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(gesture.location(in: gesture.view!))
    case UIGestureRecognizerState.ended:
        collectionView?.endInteractiveMovement()
    default:
        collectionView?.cancelInteractiveMovement()
    }
}


import UIKit

extension UIView {
    func snapshot() -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size)
        self.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image!
    }
}

extension CGPoint {
    func distanceToPoint(p:CGPoint) -> CGFloat {
        return sqrt(pow((p.x - x), 2) + pow((p.y - y), 2))
    }
}

struct SwapDescription : Hashable {
    var firstItem : Int
    var secondItem : Int

    var hashValue: Int {
        get {
            return (firstItem * 10) + secondItem
        }
    }
}

func ==(lhs: SwapDescription, rhs: SwapDescription) -> Bool {
    return lhs.firstItem == rhs.firstItem && lhs.secondItem == rhs.secondItem
}

class SwappingCollectionView: UICollectionView {

    var interactiveIndexPath : IndexPath?
    var interactiveView : UIView?
    var interactiveCell : UICollectionViewCell?
    var swapSet : Set<SwapDescription> = Set()
    var previousPoint : CGPoint?

    static let distanceDelta:CGFloat = 2 // adjust as needed

    override func beginInteractiveMovementForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool
    {
        self.interactiveIndexPath = indexPath

        self.interactiveCell = self.cellForItem(at: indexPath)

        self.interactiveView = UIImageView(image: self.interactiveCell?.snapshot())
        self.interactiveView?.frame = self.interactiveCell!.frame

        self.addSubview(self.interactiveView!)
        self.bringSubviewToFront(self.interactiveView!)

        self.interactiveCell?.isHidden = true

        return true
    }

    override func updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(_ targetPosition: CGPoint) {

        if (self.shouldSwap(newPoint: targetPosition))
        {
            if let hoverIndexPath = self.indexPathForItem(at: targetPosition), let interactiveIndexPath = self.interactiveIndexPath {

                let swapDescription = SwapDescription(firstItem: interactiveIndexPath.item, secondItem: hoverIndexPath.item)

                if (!self.swapSet.contains(swapDescription)) {

                    self.swapSet.insert(swapDescription)

                    self.performBatchUpdates({
                        self.moveItem(at: interactiveIndexPath as IndexPath, to: hoverIndexPath)
                        self.moveItem(at: hoverIndexPath, to: interactiveIndexPath)
                        }, completion: {(finished) in
                            self.swapSet.remove(swapDescription)
                            self.dataSource?.collectionView?(self, moveItemAt: interactiveIndexPath, to: hoverIndexPath)
                            self.interactiveIndexPath = hoverIndexPath

                    })
                }
            }
        }

        self.interactiveView?.center = targetPosition
        self.previousPoint = targetPosition
    }

    override func endInteractiveMovement() {
        self.cleanup()
    }

    override func cancelInteractiveMovement() {
        self.cleanup()
    }

    func cleanup() {
        self.interactiveCell?.isHidden = false
        self.interactiveView?.removeFromSuperview()
        self.interactiveView = nil
        self.interactiveCell = nil
        self.interactiveIndexPath = nil
        self.previousPoint = nil
        self.swapSet.removeAll()
    }

    func shouldSwap(newPoint: CGPoint) -> Bool {
        if let previousPoint = self.previousPoint {
            let distance = previousPoint.distanceToPoint(p: newPoint)
            return distance < SwappingCollectionView.distanceDelta
        }

        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: You really don't need the 'self.' for every line of code in there...

Comment: I know, just my preferred style. Feel free adapt it to your own preferred style.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to track numbers of cells being dragged like this behaviour:

```
@objc func handleLongPressGesture(_ gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

    switch gesture.state {
    case .began:
        guard let targetIndexPath = reorderCollectionView.indexPathForItem(at: gesture.location(in: reorderCollectionView)) else {
            return
        }
        reorderCollectionView.beginInteractiveMovementForItem(at: targetIndexPath)
   

    case .changed:
        reorderCollectionView.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(gesture.location(in: reorderCollectionView))
        reorderCollectionView.performBatchUpdates {
            self.reorderCollectionView.visibleCells.compactMap { $0 as? ReorderCell}
                .enumerated()
                .forEach { (index, cell)  in
                    cell.countLabel.text = "\(index + 1)"
                }
        }
       
        
    case .ended:
        reorderCollectionView.endInteractiveMovement()
    default:
        reorderCollectionView.cancelInteractiveMovement()
    }

}
```