# Duplicated Cell Animation During Batch Update

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have set up a collectionView to have custom reordering behavior [via the solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39172207/custom-cell-reorder-behavior-in-collectionview)

However, when a cell is quickly dragged to a new row, the animation shows the dragged cell animate from its original position again (see below):

[image]

[image]

I am wondering how I could have it just drop the dragged cell at the row it's been dragged to, rather than showing it animate from its original cell again.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this well by increasing the setting the dragged cell's layer.speed property when the interactive movement begins, and then setting it back to 1 when the batchUpdates are completed.