# UICollectionView cell snaps to original position when dragged on iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionViewController` that uses the interactive movement APIs to support reordering of cells. When a cell is dragged to a different position, then back to its original position, it snaps/jumps into place. This only occurs on iOS 13, and does not occur on iOS 11 or iOS 12.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xRrN.jpg

I use the following method to handle long presses of collection view cells:

```
@objc private func handleLongPress(_ recognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    switch recognizer.state {
    case .began:
        guard let selectedIndexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: recognizer.location(in: collectionView)) else {
            break
        }
        collectionView.beginInteractiveMovementForItem(at: selectedIndexPath)

    case .changed:
        collectionView.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(recognizer.location(in: collectionView))

    case .ended:
        collectionView.endInteractiveMovement()

    default:
        collectionView.cancelInteractiveMovement()
    }
}
```

A minimal reproducible example is available here: https://github.com/wsun/ios13DragDrop

I'd like to stick to the interactive movement APIs instead of using the newer iOS 11 drag/drop API since it allows control over where the user can drag cells to. Since I'm not doing anything particularly novel, I suspect this may be a UIKit regression in iOS 13. Does anyone have any suggestions or workarounds to address this issue?

Comment: Your code refers to many unknown methods. That makes it impossible to know in detail what you are doing.

Comment: @matt I appreciate the feedback, I've removed those methods - they are irrelevant for this behavior. I've added a minimal reproducible example to the question as well.

Comment: @wsun I facing the same problem, did you find solution?

Comment: @sash, just added my solution - hopefully helpful!

Comment: It seems to be a bug on iOS 13. Check this [radar://7401200](https://openradar.appspot.com/7401200).

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS11 drag and drop is built into CollectionViews so you don't need to do this anymore.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/collection_views/supporting_drag_and_drop_in_collection_views

Comment: I appreciate the answer! However, I'm not sure the iOS 11 drag/drop APIs work for my situation - I'd like to control the drag motion (e.g. lock to vertical axis only, as shown in the video), and `UICollectionViewDragDelegate` doesn't provide an interface to control this like the older interactive movement API does with `updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition`

Comment: I haven't read through all that article but not declaring the drag/drop delegates to the collectionView has fixed it for me. but this also means you can't have contextMenuConfigurationForItemAt; probably because they're both long presses

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of fiddling around, I decided to go ahead and implement my own collection view movement API, which mirrors the methods `beginInteractiveMovementForItem`, `updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition`, and `endInteractiveMovement`.

This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39186150) helpfully illustrated the kind of internal logic you'd have to re-implement, and if appropriate, you'll need to implement scroll on drag and placeholder cells too. In particular, you'll create a snapshot of the dragged cell (hiding the original cell temporarily) and update the position/styling of the temporary snapshot cell as you drag it.

This is a bunch of work that Apple mostly has taken care of already, so if you don't absolutely need control over the drag or swap behavior, definitely recommend using the iOS 11 drag APIs instead (mentioned by @trapper).

I found that someone else seems to have filed a [radar](http://www.openradar.me/7401200) regarding this behavior, so hopefully Apple will take notice and fix at some point in the future!

Comment: december 1th, 2020, problem still occuring on iOS 13...